# PHP Send To Outlook PDF file

Tags: php, pdf, outlook, fpdf

i'm used fpdf for create pdf with php.  everything are ok. but i want to send pdf file to outlook.

I'm using `$pdf->Output('file.pdf','D');`

it's running. I want to attachment this file to microsoft outlook.

How i can this ?

Answer (score 1):

Something you can do is save the file to a temporary location on the server, and then use something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to attach that saved file to the email. PHPMailer is a lot easier to use for attachments than PHP's built-in [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

You can temporarily store your PDF file a number of ways. Here's one:

```
$tempfilename = time().'.pdf';
$pdf->Output($tempfilename,'F');
```

Then in PHPMailer, you can attach it as such:

```
$mail->addAttachment($tempfilename);
```

And then after you are done, you can remove the temporary file from the server.

```
unlink($tempfilename);
```

If PHPMailer is not possible to use for your situation for whatever reason, you can use PHP's built-in [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. If you're working from a fresh file or a small file where the cost of adding PHPMailer is relatively small, do that if you can. Otherwise, you may try adding code like this to your `$headers`. Adapted from an answer on using [`mail` to send attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12313090/4770933):

```
//  Generate a random hash to send mixed content
$sep = md5(time());

//  End of line
$eol = PHP_EOL;

//  Content of file
$content = file_get_contents($tempfilename);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

//  Add attachment to headers
$headers .= "--" . $sep . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $tempfilename . "\"" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol . $eol;
$headers .= $content . $eol . $eol;
$headers .= "--" . $sep . "--";
```